# First three values of a string /000/ must match the first three values of a long number 0007689 oracle

Tags: oracle

My table has:

```
column1
TX/W/000/W/0001292SC_00_11-11-091-26W2_2.pdf
TX/W/000/TO/0001222/TX_Code_0001222.pdf
TX/W/000/TO/0001982/TX_Code_0001982.pdf
TX/W/000/TO/0002216/TX_Code_0002216.pdf
TX/W/000/TO/0006002/TX_Code_0006002.pdf
TX/W/006/CA/TX_WCA_006928.PDF
TX/W/702/TO/7021/TO_Data Transmittal_00_11-09-029-21W2_0_2.pdf
TX/W/000/CA/TX_WCA_0007902.PDF
```

TX/W/011/CA/TX_WDA_0008902.PDF

My current query is:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR (Column1,'\d{4,7}') as Result_set from table1
```

which gets

```
Result set 
0001292
0001222
0001982
0002216
0006002
006928
7021
0007902
0008902
```

I have edited my question, it was not clear before, I am so sorry about that.

I would like the three values /006/ to match the first three values of 006928 using `Regexp_Substr()`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

For example (006) values should be the first values in the long number 006928, if not then ignore.

Comment: Why shouldn't that match 0006002 as well - or should it? What output are you actually expecting to see from your query?

Comment: if REGEXP_LIKE (path,'\d{3} exist in  REGEXP_SUBSTR (PATH,'\d{4,7}')  then REGEXP_SUBSTR (PATH,'\d{4,7}')  should be returnedl;  Thats how I can simplify it.

Comment: Is it the three-digit string that you need to find in the longer string of digits? Or are you, in fact, looking to match the third token (between the second and the third forward slash) against the fifth token? That would make much more sense, and is actually easier to code.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is to isolate the three-digit string between the second and the third slash, and then to see if this three-digit pattern can be found after the fourth slash, you could do something like this. You don't need the WITH clause (I included it for testing, but you have your actual table and actual column name); the query begins at `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR...`

```
with
  table1 (column1) as (
    select 'TX/W/000/W/0001292SC_00_11-11-091-26W2_2.pdf' from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0001222/TX_Code_0001222.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0001982/TX_Code_0001982.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0002216/TX_Code_0002216.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0006002/TX_Code_0006002.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/006/CA/TX_WCA_006928.PDF'                from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/702/TO/7021/TO_Data Transmittal_00_11-09-029-21W2_0_2.pdf' 
                                                          from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/CA/TX_WCA_0007902.PDF'               from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(column1, '\d{4,7}') as result
from   table1
where  substr(column1, instr(column1, '/', 1, 4) + 1)
       like
       '%' || substr(column1, instr(column1, '/', 1, 2) + 1, 
                instr(column1, '/', 1, 3) - instr(column1, '/', 1, 2) - 1) 
           || '%'
;

RESULT                                                        
--------
0001292
0001222
0001982
0002216
0006002
006928
7021
0007902
```

Comment: It still returns the non-matching values .  for example if  select 'TX/W/001/TO/0001982/TX_Code_0001982.pd it shouldn't return anything but for some reason its returning everything even if they don't match.  I am sorry on my example, I did not include data that don't match, sorry about that.  Can you  help me to ignore the ones that don't match and only include the matching values.  Thank you.

Comment: @Vow -   001 DOES match 0001982, or else you have some unusual definition of "match".

Comment: @mathguy- They don't match in the sense that  the 3 digits  are 001 and the fist three on the 0001982 is 000, The first three values must match exactly as the first 3 digits in 0001982

Comment: @Vow - if you work with computers, you will need to learn to use common language with much more precision. In the problem statement (original post) you said "digits ... should be found in the longer number" - you didn't say "should be found **at the beginning** of the longer number", which is different. Please update your question (and DO state that you made a change, don't just edit with no explanation), then I will show you how to solve this different question. I can't read your mind, and neither can anyone else.

Comment: I have edited my question,thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for the modified (edited) question.

**Assumptions:** the input string has a three-digit string between the second and the third forward slash. If the substring starting at the fourth forward slash contains a sub-substring of four or more consecutive digits, take the first such occurrence, and return the row only if the first three digits of this substring equals the substring found between the second and the third forward slash.

NOTE: The OP keeps looking for a string of digits between four and seven digits long. But with nothing following `\d{4, 7}`, this will match strings of digits of any length greater or equal to 4. If the requirement is that the string of digits in the "fifth token" be no longer than 7 digits, that can be accommodated, but it didn't seem to be part of the problem.

With that said:  (notice that the last row, which I added for further testing, is NOT selected in the output - only matching at the BEGINNING of the string of 4-7 digits is valid, matching later in the string is not enough).

```
with
  table1 (column1) as (
    select 'TX/W/000/W/0001292SC_00_11-11-091-26W2_2.pdf' from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0001222/TX_Code_0001222.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0001982/TX_Code_0001982.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0002216/TX_Code_0002216.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/TO/0006002/TX_Code_0006002.pdf'      from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/006/CA/TX_WCA_006928.PDF'                from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/702/TO/7021/TO_Data Transmittal_00_11-09-029-21W2_0_2.pdf' 
                                                          from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/000/CA/TX_WCA_0007902.PDF'               from dual union all
    select 'TX/W/007/ZZ/TX_WCA_0007902.PDF'               from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(column1, '\d{4,7}') as result
from   table1
where  regexp_substr(column1, '^([^/]*/){2}(\d{3})', 1, 1, null, 2)
       =
       regexp_substr(column1, '^([^/]*/){4}\D*(\d{3})\d+', 1, 1, null, 2)
;

RESULT                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------
0001292
0001222
0001982
0002216
0006002
006928
7021
0007902
```

In `SELECT` we pick the first four to seven digits from the "long string of digits" (not sure if seven is guaranteed to be the upper bound, or if there may be longer strings of digits but at most seven digits must be selected, etc.)

The first regular expression in the `WHERE` clause is anchored at the beginning of the string (the `^` character at the beginning of the regular expression); then it looks for two occurrences of (zero or more non-slash characters followed by one slash), and then three digits. Parentheses in a regular expression create **subexpressions**, which can be referenced in the REGEXP functions. The sixth argument, `2`, means select the second subexpression - in this case, the three digits after the second slash.

The last regular expression is similar: look for the fourth slash, followed by zero or more non-digits (`\D`) followed by three digits AS A SUBEXPRESSION (enclosed in parentheses) and immediately followed by at least one more digit (to enforce the requirement that the string of digits be at least FOUR digits long). Select the second subexpression, meaning the three digits at the beginning of the "long string of digits". Note that if no such "long string of digits" even exists, then the `WHERE` clause will automatically fail (that row will not be selected).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.  I greatly appreciate the  explanation provided.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
select regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') as result_set
from table1
where regexp_substr (regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}'), '006') is not null;
```

or with `regexp_like()`:

```
select regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') as result_set
from table1
where regexp_like (regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}'), '006');
```

or just plain non-regex `like`:

```
select regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') as result_set
from table1
where regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') like '%006%';
```

With your sample data, any of those return:

```
RESULT_SET                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------
0006002
006928
```

Comment: To use select regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') as result_set
from table1
where regexp_substr (column1,'\d{4,7}') like '%006%';  will not work for me because I  have huge anount of data and it has different three digits, like 001, 011, 12B etc, so they have to match the first three digits in the   bigger number and ignore the unmatched ones. If I use this  method you gave e, It will not work for me because of the amount of data I am dealing with.

Comment: You didn't say it needed to match the first three digits. That's much simpler. It also isn't clear int he question that the 006 is coming from earlier in the same value. Mathguy has got you close so I won't bother trying to evolve this answer.